# JavaScript HTML web scraper in PyQt5 Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, pyqt5

I'm trying to build a dynamic JavaScript web-scraping tool in the Anaconda Spyder IDE as I've been following SentDex on YouTube but I can't seem to use PyQt5 to load up a virtual HTML page for an instance of a dynamically updated element modified by JavaScript. This code only works some of the time, and usually I get just the head and body tags of a web page in place of the expected full webpage HTML source output. PyQt4 seems to be unusuable to me in Spyder for some reason and some packages are updated/deprecated. How can I change this code in Spyder or change my IDE environment to make this pull an instance of modified HTML and return the text between a required HTML element? I don't want to use Selenium since this is performance critical.

```
import bs4 as bs
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebPage

class Client(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.app.quit()

client_response = Client('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/')
source = client_response.mainFrame().toHtml()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
js_test = soup.find('p', class_='jstest')
print(js_test.text)
```

Comment: why do not you run it from the terminal or cmd without spyder?

Comment: @eyllanesc I'll have to install the packages in python manually, this is part of a big script with lots of packages and Anaconda keeps track of the packages well. I'll try and run it from the Python shell.

Comment: and what is the problem ?, use the anaconda python. Spyder is just an IDE, it is not python.

Comment: @eyllanesc Okay, suddenly all my scripts work now that I've run them from the command prompt and changed my path from Python 3.6 to Anaconda's Python. That's crazy, I don't understand Anaconda or Spyder at all. Thank you very much!